Vigilante activity at this forum
About 10 years ago I discovered Mathematics Stack Exchange on the internet. I liked the forum and  I joined, in order to help answer math questions by students. This has worked quite well, and over the years I have built a good reputation.
Later on I tried some of the other Stackexchange forums. Most were a disappointment. They had vigilante types hanging around, who enjoyed criticizing questions by newbies, voting them down and then locking the question. I suppose that is nowadays "normal behaviour" on the internet.
I discovered the hard way that Science Fiction & Fantasy is probably the worst Stackexchange forum. By now I have posted three questions, after careful consideration and using my best English. And every time there is negative commentary within minutes, followed by down votes and then closing down the question. I had no choice but to delete my first two questions, and the same will undoubtedly happen with my third.
The strange thing is that there are many questions posted by others which I consider quite poor and badly written. Yet they are well-received and upvoted. The answers are usually by 100k members, who tend to receive upvotes from each other. An incestuous situation which is tolerated?

Do you have any specific examples of questions you believe are "poor and badly-written" and should have been downvoted, but haven't been?

Sure. For example the bizarre question "Man travel through parallel universes and creature with mirror or glass mask/helmet hunting him!".

That question has some clumsy grammar, I'll grant you, but we don't downvote questions just for having poor grammar, unless they're completely impossible to understand - we just edit them, which I'll do when I have more time. It's clear, on-topic, and doesn't show any signs of lacking research - in short, I don't believe it deserves to be downvoted.

Here is another example: "70s/80s book: Male character had to keep hair long. Front cover male with massive braid over holding cat."

@M. Wind - Just from the title alone that sounds like a pretty clear and intelligible Story-ID question. Are you just objecting because their English isn't fantastic?

Vigilanteism is operating outside of the law without authority to do so. Users with enough reputation on SE sites are authorized to downvote and vote to close questions. Users without enough reputation can't even do things they aren't authorized to do. So the mechanics of SE prevent vigilanteism. Any actions taken on your content are done by people authorized to take those actions. This is part of community moderation.

Regarding your last paragraph, this is a community, and like all communities, there are norms - things that most people here prefer and things that we don't like as much. The community and its norms do change, but slowly. If you don't like the norms of this community, that is understandable. It doesn't mean those norms are invalid. There are only about 20 100k rep users here, and the top voted content here will have hundreds of votes on it, so it's not possible that only 100k+ users are upvoting. The highly voted content is popular here. If you want to post popular content, study and imitate.

What you describe as 'vigilante activity' is simply the normal process of bad questions being downvoted and then closed.
Note that you're offered the opportunity to try to get them re-opened by editing them into shape, but you've chosen to self-delete rather than engaging with the community to address the  problems that they've raised, which is why they remain closed.

Specifics;
Your most recently closed question...

Claims about "Freudian sexual horror" in the Alien film series

...was completely off-topic. In simple terms it was asking whether users felt that the writer of an article had "made valid points".
Per the [FAQ]

... avoid asking subjective questions where …
there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”


Your other question had quite a similar problem. It posed a leading question...

How do the writers of Voyager reconcile the ideas of non-sexist, gender-neutral policies on Federation starships with female officers wearing make-up?

... and then demanded that answerers agree with the premise (e.g. that wearing makeup is inherently for the male gaze). The comments showed that others disputed the validity of the question as asked.

I don't see how women wearing make-up if they want to is sexist. –
F1Krazy


The world of the future is one that is very far from being gender-neutral. Certainly things are more equal in the 2300s, but that does not mean that everyone is androgynous or asexual. –
Valorum

It's not clear what form a good answer would look like, other than somebody posting, "yeah, I guess?"

Your earliest closed (and self-deleted) question was closed because it was not clear what you were asking, and because the question was borderline a duplicate of another one.

The crashed alien spaceship in the movies "Alien" and "Aliens".

In this instance I recall thinking that while the question was meandering and over-wordy, it did actually have some merit.
Had the question been edited (with an axe) to focus on the main point it might have been reopened, however, the question was deleted fairly promptly after closure.

In conclusion, the voting system is working as it has been intended to. Poor opinion-based questions (like yours) are being closed promptly and the writer is offered the opportunity to edit them should they so desire.
Might I suggest that before asking another question, you have a think about what a good answer would look like. Would that answer be short and objective? If the answer is 'yes' then the question is probably worth asking. If the answer would require an essay to answer, then the question is not worth asking here.
